# Spring AOP logging

Tags: spring-boot, logging, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a j2ee web application running on Spring framework. I want to implement logging using log4j and Spring's AOP. I am able to log the public methods using custom annotation. I am not able to log private methods using custom annotation. can any one please give reference how to implement custom annotation for private methods.

Answer (score 1):

## Spring AOP

Spring AOP doesn't support interception of private methods.

## 11. [Supported Pointcut Designators](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#Supported%20Pointcut%20Designators)

> Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, calls within the target object are by definition not intercepted. For JDK proxies, only public interface method calls on the proxy can be intercepted. With CGLIB, public and protected method calls on the proxy will be intercepted, and even package-visible methods if necessary. However, common interactions through proxies should always be designed through public signatures.
> Note that pointcut definitions are generally matched against any intercepted method. If a pointcut is strictly meant to be public-only, even in a CGLIB proxy scenario with potential non-public interactions through proxies, it needs to be defined accordingly.
> If your interception needs include method calls or even constructors within the target class, consider the use of Spring-driven native AspectJ weaving instead of Spring’s proxy-based AOP framework. This constitutes a different mode of AOP usage with different characteristics, so be sure to make yourself familiar with weaving first before making a decision.

## AspectJ Source Weaving

You can intercept **private** methods by taking advantage of AspectJ source weaving. [Here](https://github.com/indrabasak/stackoverflow-indra/tree/master/spring-aspectj-example) is a complete working example.

Comment: i was searching for Spring-driven native AspectJ weaving example but i am not able to find the right example.

Comment: I am able to run the example but when the private method is called from public method the @before annotation is not working.

Comment: My example is calling a `private` method. Please check the `pom.xml` of my example on how to use the maven aspect plugin. Please see also see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072554/aspect-does-not-capture-method-from-scheduled/47104087#47104087) from a very similar question.

Comment: when i am using maven aspect plugin it is throwing error near execution tag.

Comment: paste the exception stack in your post.

Comment: Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.10:test-compile (execution: default, phase: compile)  .` <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                             <goal>compile</goal> 
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>`

Comment: do you have any class in your `test` folder?

Comment: no i don't have anything, i have replicated the code the one you shared me.

Comment: Then you should comment the test-compile tag. You also need to modify your point cut to includ private keyword. By default, it's public.

Comment: `<executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                             <goal>compile</goal> 
<!--                             <goal>test-compile</goal> -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>`    i have made changes to the plugin i am facing the same error:  Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.10:compile (execution: default, phase: compile)

Comment: I can take a look at your code if you check it in GitHub.