# Aspect does not capture method from Scheduled

Tags: java, spring, annotations, scheduler, spring-aop

Why is set aspect of an annotation not working when it is set to a method from cron.

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
  @Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * * * ?")
  public void schedule() {
    myMethod("test");
  }

  @MyAnno(cl = MyClass.class, description = "desc")
  private void myMethod(String text) {

  }
}

@Aspect
@Component
public MyAscpect {
  @Before("@annotation(myAnnoAnnotation)")
  public void myAnnoAspect(JoinPoint jp, MyAnno myAnnoAnnotation) {
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here. Can you be clear. you have `@scehduled` on a different method and `@MyAnno` on a different method. how does it matter?

Comment: The method myAnnoAspect never executes after calling myMethod.I have the same class structure for another annotation and it works (without @Scheduled).

Comment: You have `@Before` Annotation, that means `myAnnoAspect` should be executed before `myMethod`

Answer (score 4):

## Spring AOP

Here are the points you should remember about Spring AOP,

1. > Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, **calls within the target object** are by definition **not intercepted**.
2. > For **JDK proxies**, only **public** interface method calls on the proxy can be **intercepted**. With **CGLIB**, **public** and **protected** method calls on the proxy will be **intercepted**, and even **package-visible** methods if necessary.

You can find more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#Supported%20Pointcut%20Designators).

- Since your method `myMethod` is **private**, the call to `myMethod` will not be intercepted. Please refer to the **second point** mentioned above.
- Even if your `myMethod` was **public**, the call to `myMethod` would not have been intercepted if the call was made via `schedule` method. Please refer to the **first point** mentioned above.
- Now if your `myMethod` was **public**, the call to `myMethod` would be intercepted if the call was made directly to `myMethod` method from outside the object.

## AspectJ Source Weaving

However, you can intercept private methods by taking advantage of AspectJ source weaving. In source weaving, the weaver becomes part of the compiler. 
The weaver acts as a compiler by processing the source code and generating woven Java bytecode. Instead of `javac` compiler, it uses `ajc` compiler.

Here are the changes you need to make:

- Add Maven `aspectj-maven-plugin` plugin to your `pom.xml`
- As shown below, changes to the pointcut of `MyAspect` to include **private** methods.

  ```
  @Component
  @Aspect
  public class MyAspect {

      @Before("@annotation(myAnnoAnnotation) && execution(private * *(..))")
      public void myAnnoAspect(JoinPoint jp, MyAnno myAnnoAnnotation) {
      ...
      }
  }
  ```

  You can find a complete working example [here](https://github.com/indrabasak/stackoverflow-indra/tree/master/spring-aspectj-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Your source as following.

Of course, the application class with the main method should have @EnableScheduling attached.

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    @MyAnno
    @Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * * * ?")
    public void schedule() {
        myMethod("test");
    }
    private void myMethod(String text) {
        //TODO enter your code.
    }
}

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnno{

}

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAnnoAspect{
    @Before("@annotation(MyAnno)")
    public void myAnnoAspect(JoinPoint jp) {

    }
}
```